# using ng-repeat to retrieve data from an http response array of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to retrieve response from a laravel API using  HTTP get request in my controller and ng-repeat to loop through all data in the view, it logs all response in the console but not displaying anything in the view .
 This is my JSON object:

```
[
 {
  "id":1,
  "product_id":"ABCly119",
  "name":"Shirt",
  "category_id":"fashion",
  "color":"Grey",
  "size":"L",
  "brand":"Tims",
  "type":"Polo",
  "price":11000,
  "main_image":null,
  "vat":null,
  "description":"A very good shirt",
  "product_condition":"new",
  "created_at":"2017-07-31 14:36:17",
  "updated_at":"2017-07-31 15:37:21"},
{
  "id":2,
  "product_id":"ABCly139",
  "name":"Shirt",
  "category_id":"fashion",
  "color":"Black",
  "size":"M",
  "brand":"Tims",
  "type":"Polo",
  "price":10000,
  "main_image":null,
  "vat":null,
  "description":"A very good shirt",
  "product_condition":"new",
  "created_at":"2017-07-31 14:39:47",
  "updated_at":"2017-07-31 14:39:47"},
 {
  "id":3,
   "product_id":"ABCly139",
   "name":"Shirt",
   "category_id":"fashion",
   "color":"Blue","size":"S",
   "brand":"Tims",
   "type":"Polo",
   "price":12000,
   "main_image":null,
   "vat":null,
   "description":"A very good shirt",
   "product_condition":"new",
   "created_at":"2017-07-31 14:41:06",
   "updated_at":"2017-07-31 14:41:06"
  }
]
```

this is my controller

```
angular
.module('productsController',[])
.constant('baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product')
.controller('productCtrl',['$scope','$log','$http','baseUrl','$rootScope',function($scope,$log,$http,baseUrl,$rootScope){
    $log.info('Product controller loaded');

    $http.get(baseUrl + '/fetch')
        .then(function (response){
            $scope.response = response;

            var i = $scope.response;

            angular.forEach(i, function(item){
                $scope.product = item;
                console.log($scope.product);    
            });


            return response.data;
        },function  (error){
            $scope.error = error;
            $log.info($scope.error);
        });
}]);
```

this is my view

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in products">
        <span>{{x[0].name}}</span>
    </li>                       
</ul>
```

i tried using the code above it logs to console but not displaying on the view

Comment: You should use `service` for your backend calls, instead of using it directly inside your components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.product = item will override all the items, except the last item of i array and you better do this way below

```
    $scope.products=[];
    angular.forEach(i, function(item){
        $scope.products.push(item);
    });

 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in products">
        <span>{{x.name}}</span>
    </li>                       
</ul>
```

or below markup prints all value of name property

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in response.data">
        <span>{{x.name}}</span>
    </li>                       
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

there ir no $scope.products, just $scope.product, try

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in response">
        <span>{{x[0].name}}</span>
    </li>                       
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think each item in `$scope.response` in an array, so you should get rid of the first array index and just have: `{{x.name}}`

Comment: as in the question shows, the response IS and array, you can iterate on that.

Comment: I'm well aware that `$scope.response` is an array, but your code suggests that each item in that array is an array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to:

```
angular
.module('productsController',[])
.constant('baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product')
.controller('productCtrl',['$scope','$log','$http','baseUrl','$rootScope',function($scope,$log,$http,baseUrl,$rootScope){
    $log.info('Product controller loaded');

    $http.get(baseUrl + '/fetch')
        .then(function (response){
            $scope.products = response
        },function  (error){
            $log.info(error);
        });
}]);
```

and your view to:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in products">
        <span>{{x.name}}</span>
    </li>                       
</ul>
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: sorry but it didnt work. i had also tried this earlier.

Comment: Your response object seems to be a bit odd if it doesn't have a data member. You should not need to  iterate through the array and push the elements to another array. I'm going to edit this answer to reflect that.